# I managed to fetch data from my firebase which contains images however how do I get the image data from firebase storage on react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Currently im still new on react.js. I have managed to bring the data from my firebase to be shown on my website. However, I know that the database will return only a string url for the image. How do i get the data from my firebase storage? Below is my code.

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { imgDB , db } from '../firebaseConfig'
import { getDocs, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';


async function fetchDataFromFireStore(){
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"rewards"))

    const data = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
            data.push({ id:doc.id,...doc.data()});
    });
    return data;
}


const RDatabase = () => {
 
   const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);


   useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const data = await fetchDataFromFireStore();
        setUserData(data);
    }
    fetchData();
    
   },[]);
   
    // Display the result on the page
    return (
        <div className='bg-gray-100 w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col p-4 md:my-0 my-8 rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300'>
                <h2>Student Details</h2>
                 <div>
                    {userData.map((user) => (
                        <div key={user.id}>
                            <p>{user.brand}</p>
                            <p>{user.name}</p>
                            <p>{user.price}</p>
                            <img src={user.main_image}  />
                        </div>
                    ))}

                 </div>
               

        
        </div>
 
    );
}
 

 
export default RDatabase;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood you want read the image URL from Firestore, and then load that image from Cloud Storage.

This is how you can do it in react:

```
async function fetchImageData() {
  const updatedUserData = await Promise.all(
    userData.map(async (user) => {
      const imageRef = ref(imgDB, user.main_image); // Assuming 'main_image' contains the image path in Storage
      try {
        const url = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
        return { ...user, imageUrl: url }; // Adding imageUrl to user object
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
        return user;
      }
    })
  );
  setUserData(updatedUserData);
}
```

Then add this `useEffect` in your code after the first `useEffect` to call the function and get the image url:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch image data for each user
  async function fetchImageData() {
    const updatedUserData = await Promise.all(
      userData.map(async (user) => {
        const imageRef = ref(imgDB, user.main_image); // Assuming 'main_image' contains the image path in Storage
        try {
          const url = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
          return { ...user, imageUrl: url }; // Adding imageUrl to user object
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
          return user;
        }
      })
    );
    setUserData(updatedUserData);
  }

  if (userData.length > 0) {
    fetchImageData();
  }
}, [userData]);
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked! May I ask what does the Promise do?

Comment: Your welcome @MuqriHafiy I use the Promis to wait until I get the image